# Why a single piece of optical fibre is not used rather a light pipe is used?

Tags: optical-materials

A bundle of optical fibres called a light pipe is used.A single optical fibre is not used to see the complete image.

Comment: Howe would you bend a single optical fibre?

Answer (score 1):

When a solid object is bent, the inner layers experience contraction and the outer layers experience tension. The further the layers are from the neutral line, the greater is the strain/stress.

[image]

Optic fibres are made from brittle material, there is only so much strain it can endure before breaking. So the smaller the bending radius you want your fibres to withstand, the thinner you need them to be. The principal difference between a bundle of fibres and a thick fibre is that in a bundle, fibres can slide between themselves, whereas in a thick fibre, “sub-fibres” are glued laterally and will experience larger strains.

Comment: Maybe you should add that "one does not want the fiber to break" it is implicit in your description, but not explicit.